# Using reflection to create a class that implements an interface of type T

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a strange reflection problem.

Refer to the class `FooAttempt1` that implements the interface `IFooAttempt1` which has a property that returns an `IAnimal`.  In the case of `FooAttempt1` it is returning a `Dog`.

In the program in question, our classes that implement `IFooAttempt1` are instantiated, do some work and then store their own reflected type and a key to the database and are later rehydrated using reflection. There are many such classes that implement `IFooAttempt1` and it is an architecture that is working quite well.

You can see the basic process at work in the method `Attempt1()`.

The problem is that that real classes are slightly more complex than `IFooAttempt1` and it is easy to make a mistake.  As such we have refactored the code slightly to use generics to help ensure that these classes are implemented correctly.

Refer to `FooAttempt2` which implements a generic `interface IFooAttempt2 < T > where T : IAnimal`.

This ensures that the Animal property is now defined as

```
public Dog Animal
```

rather than

```
public IAnimal Animal
```

Both `IFooAttempt1` and `IFooAttempt2` are functionally identical but this self-documenting feature of generics makes implementing our rather more complex classes very simple.

The problem comes when you refer to the `Attempt2()` code.   When using reflection to recreate `FooAttempt2` the line

```
object o = constructor.Invoke(null);
IFooAttempt2<IAnimal> foo2 = (IFooAttempt2<IAnimal>) o;
```

displays the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in 
ConsoleApplication1.exe Additional information: Unable to cast object of 
type 'ConsoleApplication1.FooAttempt2' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.IFooAttempt2`1
[ConsoleApplication1.IAnimal]'.
```

I can understand its point but how do you do this using reflection?

In the immediate window, if you go

```
? o
{ConsoleApplication1.FooAttempt2}
Animal: {ConsoleApplication1.Dog}
```

so it has reflected correctly.  I just can't cast it to a (`IFooAttempt2<IAnimal>`) even though `FooAttempt2` is a defined as `IFooAttempt2<Dog>` where `Dog` is an `IAnimal`.

My immediate thought was to try to do this

```
Type type = assembly.GetType(className, false, true).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(IAnimal) });
```

but it does not compile.  Evidently the compiler does not like the `typeof(interface)`

At this stage I am totally stuck.

Thanks!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Attempt1();
        Attempt2();
    }


    static void Attempt1()
    {
        FooAttempt1 foo = new FooAttempt1();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Animal.MakeNoise());

        string className = foo.GetType().FullName;

        // -----

        // get the assembly
        Assembly assembly = typeof(FooAttempt1).Assembly;

        // get the class
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className, false, true);

        // create an instance
        ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

        IFooAttempt1 foo2 = (IFooAttempt1)constructor.Invoke(null);
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Animal.MakeNoise());

    }


    static void Attempt2()
    {
        FooAttempt2 foo = new FooAttempt2();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Animal.MakeNoise());

        string className = foo.GetType().FullName;

        // -----

        // get the assembly
        Assembly assembly = typeof(FooAttempt2).Assembly;

        // get the class
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className, false, true);

        // create an instance
        ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

        object o = constructor.Invoke(null);
        IFooAttempt2<IAnimal> foo2 = (IFooAttempt2<IAnimal>) o;  // << PROBLEM HERE
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Animal.MakeNoise());
    }
}


public interface IAnimal
{
    string MakeNoise();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string MakeNoise()
    {
        return "Bark";
    }
}

public interface IFooAttempt1
{
    IAnimal Animal
    { 
        get; 
    }
}

public class FooAttempt1 : IFooAttempt1
{
    public FooAttempt1()
    {
    }

    public IAnimal Animal
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new Dog(); 
        }
    }
}


public interface IFooAttempt2<T>
    where T : IAnimal 
{
    T Animal
    { 
        get; 
    }
}

public class FooAttempt2 : IFooAttempt2<Dog>
{
    public FooAttempt2()
    {
    }

    public Dog Animal
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well written question, more of these please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `IFooAttempt2` covariant in `T`:

```
public interface IFooAttempt2<out T>
    where T : IAnimal 
{
    T Animal
    { 
        get; 
    }
}
```

then the cast to `IFooAttempt2<IAnimal>` will succeed.